# Unable to run two sets of tests using Mockgoose through grunt

Tags: node.js, mongodb, unit-testing, mongoose, gruntjs

I have two sets of mocha tests, both of which use mockgoose to mock a mongo database. If I run them independently from the command line, everything works fine. But if I have both tests together in a gruntfile whichever test goes second is unable to connect to the database.

Here's my gruntfile:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-mocha-test');
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        mochaTest: {
            unitTests: {
                options: {
                reporter: 'mocha-jenkins-reporter',
                reporterOptions: {
                    junit_report_name: "Unit Tests",
                    junit_report_path: "tests/unitTestResults.xml",
                    junit_report_stack: 1
                },
                quiet: false, 
                clearRequireCache: true
                },
            src: ['tests/unit/dbFunctionMockTests.js']
            }, apiTests: {
                options: {
                reporter: 'mocha-jenkins-reporter',
                reporterOptions: {
                    junit_report_name: "API Tests",
                    junit_report_path: "tests/apiTestResults.xml",
                    junit_report_stack: 1
                },
                quiet: false, 
                clearRequireCache: true
                },
            src: ['tests/apiTests.js']
            }
        }
    });
    grunt.registerTask('default', 'mochaTest');
}
```

Here's the code that connects to the mocked database (it's the same in apiTests.js and dbFunctionMockTests.js

```
var mockgoose = require('mockgoose');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mockgoose(mongoose)

before(function(done) {
    this.timeout(10000);
    console.log('here') //logs in both tests
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://api.test/TestingDB', function(err) {
        console.log('here too') //only shows up in the first test
        done()
    })
})
```

Does anyone know what is causing this or how to fix it? I'd really prefer to be able to run all my tests from a single grunt file.